# Label size and displaying it in foreground

Tags: d3.js

I am playing with an example [**Force Dragging III**](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ad70335eeef6d167bc36fd3c04378048)  given on *bl.ocks.org*.

I am able to load the color, size, and label of the arc/node from JSON but I am facing following 3 issues: 
1. Not able to specify the size of the label.
2. the label is hiding behind the circle, how to bring it in the foreground.
3. Though it's trivial i see a white line in all of the circle (arc starting position)

[image: network]

Code I tweaked in the example above :

```
function drawNode(d) {
  context.beginPath(); 
  context.moveTo(d.x + 3, d.y);
  context.arc(d.x, d.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle = colors(d.group); 
  context.fill();
  context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
  context.fillText(d.label, d.x,d.y);
  context.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be nice if you provide a fiddle with the tweaks you made but anyway I knew your code in the previous question that you'd asked about setting the color of nodes. I was just about to answer but saw Andrew's perfect answer to it.

Anyway, here's a fork:
https://bl.ocks.org/shashank2104/daa2fb78c966581d4ae35d6b98ec14d9/8d8fbb6caf0a37e4cd9b8d8236cbcad5ea149ce4

1. Size of the label can be defined with the help of `context.font` property. Check out [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font) on how to change this value. I used default value to be `13px`. I'm not sure how are you going to pass this size but I'd recommend to create a new d3 linear scale for size.

   ```
   context.font = (d.labelSize ? d.labelSize : 13)+'px Arial';
   ```
2. As you were applying the same color for the labels and the nodes, the labels *looked* like hidden but they actually weren't because you're maintaining the order of drawing the circles first and then the texts. It's just a matter of using a different color. I've created a new color scale for labels. (And I'm just using the group names as labels for testing).

   ```
   labelColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['white', 'orange', 'blue', 'black', 'purple']);
   ```
3. This one is interesting. The white line is due to the `x` value you use in the `context.moveTo()` function. The canvas context moves to `d.x+3` is equal to **center of the circle + 3px** and starts drawing an arc. To do that, it moves to the right by 7px (due to radius being 10) and starts drawing a circle. And as you have the `strokeStyle` set to `#fff`, you see the white line. To fix this, I've changed the `context.moveTo()` to the following:

   ```
   context.moveTo(d.x+10, d.y);
   ```

   which will move onto the arc itself and draw a circle.

Here's the new function:

```
function drawNode(d) {
  context.beginPath(); 
  context.moveTo(d.x+10, d.y);
  context.arc(d.x, d.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
  context.stroke();  
  context.fillStyle = nodeColors(d.group); 
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.beginPath();  
  context.font = (d.labelSize ? d.labelSize : 13)+'px Arial';
  context.fillStyle = labelColors(d.group);
  context.fillText(d.label ? d.label : d.group, d.x,d.y);
  context.closePath();
}
```

**Note:**

It's always advised to use `context.beginPath()` and `context.closePath()` when you're drawing something on a canvas in a loop.

Hope this makes sense. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I guess its only fair you beat me to it here, I was about to submit an answer for this one too. Nice answer.

Comment: Haha true. Thanks. I did double-check a couple of times for an answer from you while writing it and then posted it. Anyway, glad we could help resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewReid and Shashank for all your kind help. I burnt my hands trying sigma.js and was not able to do much hence dropped the idea after playing with examples for 2 days; I was initially skeptical while trying d3 but you guys (d3 community overall ) have been very helpful, I think I am now in a very good position to start working on what is in my mind. I'll be posting few more queries and hopefully, when done I will share my blog post with the end result.

Comment: Sure @nyi. No problem. Glad we could help you out. d3 is just fantastic and so is canvas. Yep, look forward to answering your queries (if any) and yes, do share the blog post. Have fun coding! :)